# Cassandra terminates if no space in disk

Tags: java, cassandra

I am using Cassandra DB in my java application. Am using Thrift client to connect Cassandra from my java application. If the Cassandra disk get full means it automatically terminates. So from my java program i could not find the correct error why the Cassandra is down.

So how to avoid the auto termination of Cassandra or is their any way to identify the disk full error ?

Also i dont have physical access to cassandra drive. Its running in some other remote machine.

Answer (score 3):

Disk errors and, in general, generic hardware/system errors are not *usually* properly handled in any application. The database should only provide as much durability as possible in such scenarios and it is the correct behavior - shut down and break as little as possible.

As for your application - if you can not connect to the database, there is no difference as to what caused an error. You app will not work anyway.

There are special tools that can monitor your machine, i.e. [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/). If you are the administrator of that server, use such applications. When the disk is getting filled up you will receive an email or text. Use such tools and don't break an open door by implementing several hundred of lines of code to handle random and very rare situations.

Comment: Most of the application there are handling the disk space exception. Example in solr they are throwing "There is not enough space on the disk" error. But after throwing the error still solr running. Like that can we do anything in Cassandra without stoping the service. Is any option available ?

Comment: Also i am running more Cassandra in many systems. So it is hard to monitor all of the services using third party tool. If service stoped means app will not work anyway ok but user don't the exact reason know. If he know the reason then only will fix it know.

Comment: These tools are made *exactly* for the purpose of monitoring multiple systems! Did you even check out the link I posted in my answer> Seriously, don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: Ya checked that. But already i am running more services. Why i have to add one more. Just i need to know whether Cassandra contains any default option or not . Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

Setup ssh access to Casandra machine and use some ssh client like [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to run `df /casandra/drive` (if Linux) or `fsutil volume diskfree c:\casandra\drive` (if Windows) from your Java client. Capture output that is simple and parse to obtain the free disk space. That way your application will monitor that is happening there and probably should alert the user and refuse to add data if there is an out of disk space threat.

You can also use standard monitoring tools or setup server side script to send the message if the disk space low. However this will not stop your application from crashing, you need to take actions after you see that the disk space is low.

Comment: I am running many Cassandra services from many systems. So for each system i need to run a third party tool , its hard to implement also hard to add new service.

Comment: I somehow assumed you already can to ssh into these systems anyway.